# asp.net mvc core 3.1 area based routing

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to include area based routing in my project. I tried a few thing but nothing seems to make sense

I have a sites area and the following routing in Startup.cs

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                name: "Sites",
                areaName: "Sites",
                pattern: "Sites/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

When trying to access the following url(project settings as in the image), i am getting directed to Home/Index which is the default mapping outside the area.

However, if I create a link the Default Home controller as such

```
<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Home" asp-area="Sites">Create</a>
```

I correctly get redirected to the area controller but the generated url is pretty confusing

```
https://localhost:44379/Sites/Home/Index/sites/home/create
```

I was thinking the following url will redirect to the Area controller Sites based on the Url. Am i missing something?

```
https://localhost:44379/Sites/Home/Index
```

Directory structure is represented here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The issue relates to the App URL and SSL URL (In the Application Properties, Debug panel), when using Anchor Tag Helper to generate the URL, it will append the URL at the end of the App URL, so it will cause this behavior.

To solve this issue, change the App URL from `https://localhost:44379/Sites/Home/Index/` to `https://localhost:44379/`.

In the Properties folder, open the `launchSettings.json` file, change the content as below:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64670",
      "sslPort": 44307
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Based on your code, I tried to add a HomeController in the Sites area using the following code:

```
[Area("sites")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then, using the following code to add hyperlinks:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Sites" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Sites Index</a>
<br />
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Sites" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">Sites Home About</a>
<br /> 
<a href="/Sites/Home/index">Sites Index</a>
```

The App URL like this:

[image]

The generated URL as below (after redirection, it still using the correct URL):

[image]

**Update**:

To set the areas page as the start page, you could use the `[Route]` attribute in the action method in the areas page. Code as below:

HomeController.cs (In the Sites area and Controllers folder)

```
[Area("Sites")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Route("")]
    [Route("Sites/Home/About")]
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

[**Note**] There is no need to set Launch browser, App URL or Enable SSL url in the application properties.

The result like this: In this sample, the default page is the about page, and it doesn't contain the confusing URL.

[image]

Comment: I tried this, the first problem, I misunderstood App Url. App Url = Base Url.. which is what you have highlighted correctly. How can i set the Area->Controller->Action as the page that gets served when I run the application in development machine. I tried your example and then putting Sites/Home/Create in the LaunchBrowser but still the default home page is the one that gets served at start up

Comment: @user1131926, Yes, you are right, if entered the `https://localhost:44307/Sites/Home/Index` or `Sites/Home/Index` in the LaunchBrowser, when we using Anchor Tag and `asp-*` to add link, after redirecting, it will also generate a confusing url like this `https://localhost:44307/Sites/Home/Index/sites/home/create`.  But, if we use set the Anchor tag using `<a href="/Sites/Home/index">Sites Index</a>`, the URL is correct. So, to generate the correct url, you can clear the LaunchBrowser or set the href attribute for the anchor tag.

Comment: correct, but what change do I need to do in order to serve  sites/home/create as the startup url?

Comment: Hi @user1131926, Please check my update in the reply. To set the areas page as the start page, you could use the [Route] attribute in the action method in the areas page. There is no need to set Launch browser, App URL or Enable SSL URL in the application properties.

Comment: I tried that and does not seem to work, i still get the default page as startup. There must be an easy way to change the startup page.

Comment: Sorry, had put the attribute  in the wrong place. works! Thanks very much